# how to use the photo picker and specify a folder

Tags: android

I've been looking into the photo picker which I want to use as part of an application I am developing. I have set up the picker to respond to intents and have tested it in my application. However the way I am hoping to use the photo picker is to restrict it to a specific folder on the SD card. Is this possible, I have looked through the API/SDK and have not found the information I was looking for.

Comment: Must you restrict it to only one folder? I don't know if that's possible, as when I worked with it I deliberately wanted the opposite. However just in case you were having trouble with the photo picking intent itself, here is some example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-for-my-app-in-android/2508138#2508138