# android activity callback

Tags: android

I'm doing application, I have mainscreen and calling next screen by main screen. In nextscreen by selecting image in gallery I wanted to go back main screen by getting image url. How to do this?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-for-my-app-in-android).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pick a image from gallery for my app in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-for-my-app-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

You should call the second Activity by [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)). Then there you return the image url as the result of the second acitivty to the first activity. The result of the second activity you can get  in the first activity in the method [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))