# Android+get selected item from listView and populate selected item into editText

Tags: android

I have an activity onClick of EditText opens a listView(another activity).
Now I need to select item from listView and update the EditText in previous activity.
Checked online and found that could not get exactly what I wanted.
Are there any helpful links?

Comment: Here's a great example on how you can implement your need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938434/android-activity-callback

Comment: please post what have you tried