# Android-Replace one image by another image

Tags: android

I am new to android.I have a image which is declared in xml file using imageView.The problem is onRuntime I want to replace that with any image from gallery when the image is long clicked.what should I have to do.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the code to replace your image at LongClickListener ,

```
imageview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ((ImageView) v).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And to get the idea to access image form gallery, refer this [how to pick a image from gallery (SD Card) for my app in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use

```
public void setImageResource (int resId);
```

method of ImageView class.