# how to upload image captured from camera in an android app

Tags: android, image, url, camera

in my app i have placed a button called Add Photo, when the user clicks the button a pop up menu appears with 2 option camera and library. When i select library i am able to move to the photo album of the device. Following is the code which i am using to go to the mobile library

`public void library()
     {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
         myIntent.setType("image/*");
         startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
     }`

whatever image i click there i want it to be uploaded in an url,

in the same way the image which i capture through the camera also want to be uploaded in an url.

how to do this is there any API or example code pls help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This SO answer explains how to get the true path of the image in your onActivityResult

[How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)

Then look for an example on how to upload a file using http, any Java example ought to work, for instance:

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=62798