# How can I reduce the size of a picture I received via share intent on Android?

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, resolution

I want to reduce the resolution/size of a picture I received via share intent and I only have its URI.
The pictures can be in different formats and I may receive several pictures at once. I used the following intent-filter:

```
 <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Share">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
  <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
 </intent-filter>
```

How can I do it?

Do I have to save the picture(s) to the SD card again with another name if I want to share it/them again with another app?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this question, then getting it working for one image, then if you are stuck on an array of strings, then ask that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Bitmap.compress(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) API.

**Edit**
To copy and scaledown the picture. Create a new empty bitmap, use it as a place for a canvas to draw to. Draw the old bitmap on the canvas with an appropriate Scale matrix or draw the old bitmap with a destination rectangle the same dimensions as your destination bitmap (depending on the api and effect you'd like to have), then save the destination bitmap.

Or for only scaling use [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29).

Comment: I want to reduce the size in pixels of the picture(s), not the accuracy. Like rescaling it. Any idea?