# Android : file in and out usb/sdcard

Tags: android, file-io

Can someone please point me in the right direction.  I have been googling for ages and I'm not getting great results.

I want my app to allow the user to download a file from the USB/SDcard.  Specifically an image, which then later gets used in my app.

I can't seem to find anything, been searching for  open file dialogs and nothing..

So:

1) User inserts USB device/SDCard.
2) User gets file browser dialog.
3) User finds image from USB/SDCard
4) App grabs image and stores it for later use.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is how to work with external storage in Android. there is a very  good tutorial from android site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal. hope this helps.

Comment: and that answers the other part of the question +1 right back at ya.

Answer (score 2):

To browse for images on the SDCard this thread is very helpful:

[How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)

I would suggest using the Android Gallery interface for images as it is much easier for the user than browsing files.