# Copying an image from the clipboard

Tags: android, image, clipboard, copy-paste

I want to get an image which is copied from the galley to my app.Means the image will be there in the clipboard I want to get that image can anyone help me.

I need to copy the image from the clipboard
 and I don't want it directly from the gallery.

Comment: it may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android  or http://coderzheaven.com/2011/03/select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-and-show-it-in-an-imageview/

Comment: @nik actualyy I want to paste it from the clipboard...

Comment: how do you 'copy' an image from your gallery? I don't see such an option.  It looks like images can be shared out to applications that are registered to use them and set as background... nothing more.

Comment: Try a screen capture doesnt work for everything, though

Answer (score 1):

I think this is as close as you're going to come to getting Gallery images into your app...

http://eggie5.com/8-hook-share-picture-via-menu-android

The article follows through all the way to an HTTP send of the image, but obviously you can just collect it as a byte[], and then do whatever you want with it after that.

It's not a copy/paste, but that's just not a mechanism that Android offers in this context, so, I'd do what I could with this solution.