# how To Save Image In Sql DataBase From Android Using .net WebService?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to store image in sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxA5h.png)i want to tack signature in android application & Store in in Sql DataBase Using >net Web Service Can AnBudy Tell Me It Is Possible Or Not?

i tryed this Code But It Didn't Work

```
hbitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(),   Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
hbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
b=baos.toByteArray();
XpresionHome.by=b;


String image=Base64.encodeToString(by,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

It Sote In Database But The Result Of Converting Byte To String & String To Byte Is Diffrent

Comment: use blob stype, for one, and secondly, how would base64 be not be symetrical ?