# How to store JSON object in SQLite database

Tags: android, database, json, sqlite

how do I store a JSON Object in an SQLite database?  What is the correct way?

one place is the blob type column.  if i can convert the JSON object into byte array and use Fileoutputstream

the other idea is to store in a text column as a String

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject jsonObject;

public void createJSONObject(Fields fields) {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsonObject.put("storedValue1", fields.storedValue1);
        jsonObject.put("storedValue2", fields.storedValue2);
        jsonObject.put("storedValue3", fields.storedValue3);
        jsonObject.put("storedValue4", fields.storedValue4);
        jsonObject.put("storedValue5", fields.storedValue5);
        jsonObject.put("storedValue6", fields.storedValue6);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: [JSON is *a textual representation of data*](http://json.org). So save it in a TEXT column / type affinity. Encoding it as a BLOB just makes more work/pain - don't do that! Of course, *get the actual JSON* from the `JSONObject` (which is *not* JSON). That can be done with [`jsonObject.toString()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString()).

Comment: if Sqlite is not compulsory used then my suggestion is that write File.txt file and save whole Response in file and Read it when need

Answer (score 109, accepted):

*Convert JSONObject into String and save as TEXT/ VARCHAR. While retrieving the same column convert the String into JSONObject.*

For example

***Write into DB***

```
String stringToBeInserted = jsonObject.toString();
//and insert this string into DB
```

***Read from DB***

```
String json = Read_column_value_logic_here
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

Comment: Are you aware of any performance issues by inserting it like that?

Comment: @JohnAndrews no. If you found, please update here :)

Comment: Will do. I am using that method to store base64 converted strings of images... so will see what happens

Comment: @JohnAndrews Sure. waiting for your valuable response. But better way to store image is using blob. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database.

Comment: Thanks for that! How does a blob differ from a base64 encoded imagedata string? Or is the same?

Comment: I should be faster than base64 incoding. Here no need of string coversion or encoding/ decoding. As you can see into link which I posted in my previous comment

Comment: SQLite has a new JSON extension. See oisin's comment.

Comment: @coleifer Still this is not supported in Android. By Reading oisin's answer and attached link, `JSON` is a type which can be used to store Json data into Sqlite, but in Android still this is not clear that which data type will support 'JSON' type of SQLite.

Comment: If you bother reading the docs, there is no SQLite json data type. Just a collection of functions.

Comment: SQLite JSON data type: https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/json1-a-sqlite-extension/

Comment: My assumption: this will store data of JSONobject's each element value to Sqlite database respective column name. isn't it? is this true?

Comment: Is is possible to convert a json object into a string and store that data into sqlite database ?

If it is possible then can we use that string when we have no internet connection in the app for offline mode.



@PankajKumar

Comment: @ShehramTahir Yes you can. Depending your requirement you can cached json response when it was last working... and that can be used in either error cases or can show offline data.

Comment: If the json is storing some urls of multiple images.
Then in online mode it fetches data from internet against those urls of images.


But how can we show those urls data in offline mode ?
@PankajKumar

Comment: what if the JSON had 300 key/value pairs, does this affect it?

Comment: @Seamus.Reeve definitely the data size will play a role in performance. Even parsing JSON to POJO or POJO to JSON will take more time than smaller data size.

Comment: How can you do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 52):

An alternative could be to use the new JSON extension for SQLite. I've only just come across this myself: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html This would allow you to perform a certain level of querying the stored JSON. If you used VARCHAR or TEXT to store a JSON string you would have no ability to query it. This is a great article showing its usage (in python) http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-the-sqlite-json1-and-fts5-extensions-with-python/

Comment: And here is a possible way to do it Android using NDK: https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: From the first page you linked: "The json1 extension (currently) stores JSON as ordinary text. Backwards compatibility constraints mean that SQLite is only able to store values that are NULL, integers, floating-point numbers, text, and BLOBs. It is not possible to add a sixth 'JSON' type." So yes, you are supposed to store JSON in a TEXT column, even if you would like to use the JSON extension functionality.

Answer (score 5):

There is no data types for that.. You need to store it as VARCHAR or TEXT only.. `jsonObject.toString();`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android allows you to query JSON fields (and arrays in them, I've tried it and am using it). Before that I was just storing JSON strings into a TEXT column. It supports FTS3, FTS4, & JSON1

As of July 2019, it still gets version bumps every now and then, so it isn't a dead project.

- https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html (store and query JSON documents)
- https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html (perform full-text searches)

Answer (score -14):

https://github.com/app-z/Json-to-SQLite

At first generate Plain Old Java Objects from JSON http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Main method

void createDb(String dbName, String tableName, List dataList, Field[] fields){
...

Fields name will create dynamically