# Best way to Insert JSON data into MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, json

I have a JSON data in a text file which contains pair of latitude and longitude,Now I want to store this data into MYSQL DB,How to go about & what's the best approach please suggest.

Here is My JSON data

```
[{"latlon":{"lng":77.75124312,"lat":12.97123123},"type":"s"}, 
 {"latlon":{"lon":77.73004942455374,"lat":12.98227579706589},"type":"s"},
 {"latlon":{"lon":77.67374449291539,"lat":12.995490063545521},"type":"v"}, 
 {"latlon":{"lon":77.6097147993144,"lat":12.970900929013666},"type":"s"},
 {"latlon":{"lon":77.53933363476645,"lat":12.948316929346504},"type":"s"},
 {"latlon":{"lng":77.48213123,"lat":12.91213213},"type":"s"}
 .
 .
 .
 .
]
The String may go up to 50 points
```

Comment: create a clob column in table and store it.

Comment: You can store it in a TEXT column. If you have a need to search based on this data, sphinx has some very good functions to parse and search JSON data.

Comment: I am using JAVA,Please suggest in that

Comment: If you use TEXT or blob you will loose the relational features of mysql. Better parse the JSON and insert the data into the table field wise.

Comment: Note that mysql 5.7 will natively support JSON as a new type of column with new functions `JSN_*` and new ways of indexing, combining nosql performance advantages on huge read load with relational advantages of searching and manipulating smaller chunks of data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some comments have suggested leaving it in JSON format and storing it in a text column.

I'd suggest that if you have control over your schema, you should store it in two `NUMERIC` fields - one for latitude, and one for longitude. Fundamentally, that's the data you have. The fact that you've received it using JSON as a container format is irrelevant to the data itself.

If you store it as a latitude and a longitude, it's simpler to query over it, and you can still recreate the JSON later if you want to... but if you end up wanting to fetch it *not* as JSON, you'll be in a much better position to do so. It also means you're not tying yourself to JSON against future changes.

Personally I think it's always a good idea to mentally separate the intrinsic nature of the data from the way that you happen to receive it. Store the data in whatever format is idiomatic for that storage - so if you're storing a number, use one of the numeric data types. If you're storing a date and time, use `datetime`, etc. That way you don't end up with an extra layer between you and the data itself every time you want to access it.

This approach also means you're much more likely to spot bad data early on - if you just store the JSON directly without parsing it first, you could *later* find that the latitude or longitude isn't a valid number. Heck, the fact that your sample data sometimes has `lon` and sometimes has `lng` suggests you should do some data cleanup anyway.

Comment: Ok,Then I have to parse it and store one-by-one

Comment: @Rakesh: Yes, I would. Indeed, I'd probably create a class to store a latitude and longitude pair, and separate out the two aspects: parsing the JSON into objects, and storing the result into the database. That way you can test each part separately, and you're not tying the two entirely separate storage/transport formats together.

Comment: Ok got the logic thanks,But if  am not using the pair in future then can we insert it as a JSON object

Comment: @Rakesh: What do you mean "if am not using the pair in future"? If you're not going to use the data, why store it at all? If you're going to read it later, why force all your various potential readers to parse the JSON each time they read it, instead of working with it in a natural, numeric form?

Comment: Sorry, got my previous question wrong.  Thank You very much for Your invaluable support.  Will get back to You, where ever I would need essential advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java for application you can do something like this.

Convert JSONObject into String and save as TEXT/ VARCHAR. While retrieving the same column convert the String into JSONObject.

For example

Write into DB

```
String stringToBeInserted = jsonObject.toString();
//and insert this string into DB
```

Read from DB

```
String json = Read_column_value_logic_here
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

Ref: [how to store JSON object in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603621/how-to-store-json-object-in-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if that's a data that matters to your software (if there will be queries involving those data), you should considere parsing the JSON.

If not : store it as it is !

Answer (score 0):

From Mysql 5.7.10 and higher JSON support is native so you can have a JSON data type

> **Document Validation** - Only valid JSON documents can be stored in a
> JSON column, so you get automatic validation of your data.
>
> **Efficient Access** - More importantly, when you store a JSON document in a JSON column, it is not stored as a plain text value. Instead, it is stored
> in an optimized binary format that allows for quicker access to object
> members and array elements.
>
> **Performance** - Improve your query
> performance by creating indexes on values within the JSON columns.
> This can be achieved with “functional indexes” on virtual columns.
>
> **Convenience** - The additional inline syntax for JSON columns makes it
> very natural to integrate Document queries within your SQL. For
> example (features.feature is a JSON column): `SELECT feature->"$.properties.STREET" AS property_street FROM features WHERE id = 121254;`