# How to save a Json String in sqlite?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have an sqlite database. The column where I want to save my JsonString in, has the data type TEXT. Everytime I want to insert a dataset I get no error until I try to read it out again, then I get an error that my curser may be at the wrong place. But when instead of a json give a usual string everything works fine. Since I don't really now what symbols might be in my json, is there at all a way to put a json into an sqlite database? (It is a large json so I can't really insert every value of it seperatly).

How can I save a JsonString else so that I can get I even if my application is closed?

I know I could put it in al file but since a database has a better structure and basiccly is a file too I would prefer to find a way working with the database.

Comment: save json.toString()

Comment: or convert to byte array and store as a BLOB object

Comment: @Blackbelt it is a json in a string so I can´t really do that

Comment: *t it is a json in a string*, then it is already a string. Save it as string

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603621/how-to-store-json-object-in-sqlite-database

Comment: it sounds like your having issues loading it from the db correct? Are you pulling it via `json = getString(int column)` and then using `new JSONObject(json)` to convert?

Comment: @RobVoisey I am not getting to new JSONObject(json) because when I get the string I get a null Pointer exeption

Comment: in that case there is something wrong with the query, post the code showing how you load it.

Comment: @RobVoisey the problem isn´t the loading. As I said when I use a normal sitring instead of the jsonString it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Save as a string:

```
json.toString();
```

Although I would parse it, it is faster this way.