# Storing image in SQLite

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am a beginner in android programming and I am trying to store information and image of different books in SQLite. I got some part of the below code from a site. I am able to store the information i.e author and title of the book but don't know how to store an image. I written the code forBook.java and MySQLiteHelper.java but don't know how to store and insert image using SQLite statement in the MainActivity.java.Can someone help?

This is my Book.java

```
 public class Book {
 int id;
 String title;
 String author;
 byte[] image;

public Book(){}

public Book(int id,String title, String author, byte[] image) {
    this.id=id;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.image=image;
}
public Book(String title, String author,byte[] image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.image=image;
}

//getters & setters
// getting ID
public int getId(){
    return this.id;
}

// setting id
public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}
// getting title
public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
}

// setting title
public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

// getting authorname
public String getAuthor(){
    return this.author;
}

// setting authorname
public void setAuthor(String author){
    this.author = author;
}
//getting image
public byte[] getImage() {
return this.image;
    }
//setting image
public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
    }
}
```

This is my MySQLitehelper.java

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookDB";
// Books table name
private static final String TABLE_BOOKS = "books";

// Books Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
}
// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create book table
    String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_BOOKS+"("+ KEY_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ KEY_TITLE+" TEXT,"+ KEY_AUTHOR+ " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ")";     

    // create books table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK_TABLE);
}
// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older books table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_BOOKS );

    // create fresh books table
    this.onCreate(db);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//*** CRUD operations (create "add", read "get", update, delete) book + get all books +      delete all books */



private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_TITLE,KEY_AUTHOR,KEY_IMAGE};

public void addBook(Book book){
    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, book.getTitle()); // get title 
    values.put(KEY_AUTHOR, book.getAuthor()); // get author
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, book.getImage()); // get author
    // 3. insert
    db.insert(TABLE_BOOKS, // table
            null, //nullColumnHack
            values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

    // 4. close
    db.close(); 
}

public Book getBook(int id){

    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor = 
            db.query(TABLE_BOOKS, // a. table
            COLUMNS, // b. column names
            " id = ?", // c. selections 
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null); // h. limit

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    // 4. build book object
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
    book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));
    book.setImage(cursor.getBlob(3));
    // 5. return book
    return book;
}

// Get All Books
public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    List<Book> books = new LinkedList<Book>();

    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BOOKS;

    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
    Book book = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            book = new Book();
            book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));
            book.setImage(cursor.getBlob(3));
            // Add book to books
            books.add(book);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return books
    return books;
}

 // Updating single book
public int updateBook(Book book) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("title", book.getTitle()); // get title 
    values.put("author", book.getAuthor()); // get author
    values.put("image", book.getImage()); // get image

    // 3. updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_BOOKS, //table
            values, // column/value
            KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) }); //selection args

}

// Deleting single book
public void deleteBook(Book book) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. delete
    db.delete(TABLE_BOOKS,
            KEY_ID+" = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(book.getId()) });

    // 3. close
    db.close();
}
}
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // add Books
    Log.d("Inserting: ", "Inserting all Books..");
    db.addBook(new Book("Android Application Development Cookbook", "Wei Meng Lee"));   
    db.addBook(new Book("Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide", "Bill Phillips and Brian Hardy"));       
    db.addBook(new Book("Learn Android App Development", "Wallace Jackson"));
   //Reading and getting all books
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all Books.."); 
    List<Book> list = db.getAllBooks();
    for (Book cn:list) {
        String log = "Id: "+cn.getId()+" ,Title: " + cn.getTitle() + " ,Author: " + cn.getAuthor() + ",Image: "+ cn.getImage();
            // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);
   // delete one book
   db.deleteBook(list.get(0));

}
}
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue..what happens when you try to store image?

Comment: you had store byte array. it's right but yet if you want another way then you can cover byte array in Base64 and store in string so you can easy get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing Image in a database you need to convert the image data to a binary form an store it in the database and when retrieving the image you need to convert it into the Bitmap format,but this is not recommended because storing images in database are somewhat tricky and complex,alternatively you can store the Image in a folder in sdcard and store only the path in the database,anyway if you still want to store the image in the database you can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database)

Comment: storing images in database are somewhat tricky and complex..!! can you please elaborate this sentence??? @insomniac

Answer (score 2):

```
public void insertImg(int id , Bitmap img ) {   


byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function

insertStatement_logo.bindLong(1, id);       
insertStatement_logo.bindBlob(2, data);

insertStatement_logo.executeInsert();
insertStatement_logo.clearBindings() ;
```

}

```
public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
return outputStream.toByteArray();
```

}

```
public Bitmap getImage(int i){

String qu = "select img  from table where feedid=" + i ;
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(qu, null);

if (cur.moveToFirst()){
    byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);
    cur.close();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
}
if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
    cur.close();
}       

return null ;
```

}

[More](http://androidroadies.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 0):

```
private String prepareImage(String imagepath) {
        if (imagepath== null) {
            return "";
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath, options);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);

        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

        String imageString = com.eg_lifestyle.utils.Base64
                .encodeBytes(byteArray);
        bitmap = null;
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        return imageString;
    }
```

i hope this is useful to you..

Answer (score 0):

This code for me. you can get proper solution

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
     ImageView imageView=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {


        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
         .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(encodedImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bmimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0,
                bytarray.length);

        myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO imgtbl VALUES('"+encodedImageString+"');");
        Cursor c= myDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM imgtbl", null);

       c.moveToFirst();
       String img=c.getString(0);
       byte[] byarray = Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
       Bitmap bmimg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byarray, 0,
               byarray.length);

        ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
        ImageView iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img3);

        iv.setImageBitmap(bmimg);
        iv1.setImageBitmap(bmimg);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```