# android - How to store image into SQL?

Tags: android, sql

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME2 = "asd";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "myreportstable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION2 = 1;

private DatabaseHelper ourdatabaseHelper;
private final Context ourdbContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourReportsDatabase;



private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME2, null, DATABASE_VERSION2);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" + KEY_ROWID2
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME2
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LOCATION2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_DISCREPTION2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +KEY_IMG2+" BLOB NOT NULL);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public ImplementsAppDB(Context c) {
    ourdbContext = c;
}

public ImplementsAppDB open() throws SQLException {
    ourdatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ourdbContext);
    ourReportsDatabase = ourdatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourdatabaseHelper.close();


}

public long CreateEntry(String name, String locationRP, String DiscreptionRP) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.home);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);


    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME2, name);
    cv.put(KEY_LOCATION2, locationRP);
    cv.put(KEY_DISCREPTION2, DiscreptionRP);
    cv.put(KEY_IMG2, out.toByteArray());

    return ourReportsDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, cv);
}
```

I want to store an image into a sqlite database. Name ,Location and Description passed from other class and image used of res.
im getting java.lang.NullPointerException when i try to insert image..
Please help.

Comment: On what line are you getting the null pointer exception

Comment: this link may help u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

Without stack trace it is hard to say, But did you call ImplementsAppDB.open() function? that will initialize ourReportsDatabase.

You can also consider to store file path in sqlite db instead of storing whole image in sqlite. Store image in your own app data and then store the file path in sqlite.