# Image storing and retrive in db through restful web sercie

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, rest, android-fragments

I am new to Android app Development. I am developing Android web app using RESTFUL web services.I have stored and retrieved my values into mySql Database. Now I have to store and retrieve image file from Database. Anyone can give simple example? or can give useful link?

Many Thanks - Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get solution from [add image and retrieve image from database in android easily](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/644248/How-to-add-and-retrieve-image-image-from-database) . I expected you will be helpful from that link.

Comment: i am using web services.but this example shows inbuild database

Comment: this link for store image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database