# Is it possible to store images in xamarin sqlite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin app for android and iOS. It uses an sqlite database.

Is it possible to store images in the database?  I can't seem to find a C# type that is allowed when defining the field type.
thanks

Comment: Blobs use byte arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to store image in sqlite database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database)

Comment: yes -that's a good answer thanks -

Comment: Hi WaterBoy! I just posted an answer to a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337487/xamarin-how-to-download-image-from-url-and-save-it-to-a-local-sqlite-database/41337488#41337488