# How to store images in sqlite database in Xamarin Forms for cross platforms application?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to store images path in **sqlite** database in **xamarin** forms for cross platform application. How to store path of image??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store image in SQLite database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database)

Comment: Show the code that you have tried so far : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not know how to do it in xamarin forms and even not getting any example for start to code so how could i write code without any information about images storage . Now, I am saving only other simple information in database like name, price etc.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=c%23+sqlite+save+bitmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i have done to save image in sqlite.And i am returning path to the image on succesful image saving, you can change it according to requirement.Here the image is stored in the form of byte array.

Link to my blog post: [Cross platform utility to save image in sqlite.](https://techytweet.wordpress.com/2016/09/18/cross-platform-utility-for-saving-images-in-sqlite/)

**Comman Interface:**

```
 public interface IFileUtility
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Use to save file in device specific folders
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="fileName"></param>
            /// <param name="fileStream"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            string SaveFile(string fileName,byte[] fileStream);

            /// <summary>
            /// Used to delete the existing file directory, before syncing the file again.
            /// </summary>
            void DeleteDirectory();

        }
```

**Android Specific Code:**

```
public class FileUtility : IFileUtility
    {
        public string SaveFile(string fileName,byte[] imageStream)
        {
            string path = null;
            string imageFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "ProductImages");

            //Check if the folder exist or not
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(imageFolderPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(imageFolderPath);
            }
            string imagefilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(imageFolderPath, fileName);

            //Try to write the file bytes to the specified location.
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(imagefilePath, imageStream);
                path = imagefilePath;
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            return path;
        }

        public void DeleteDirectory()
        {
            string imageFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "ProductImages");
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(imageFolderPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(imageFolderPath,true);
            }
        }
    }
```

**iOS Specific Code:**

```
 public class FileUtility : IFileUtility
    {
        public string SaveFile(string fileName,byte[] fileStream)
        {
            string path = null;
            string imageFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "ProductImages");

            //Check if the folder exist or not
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(imageFolderPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(imageFolderPath);
            }
            string imagefilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(imageFolderPath, fileName);

            //Try to write the file bytes to the specified location.
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(imagefilePath, fileStream);
                path = imagefilePath;
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            return path;
        }

        public void DeleteDirectory()
        {
            string imageFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "ProductImages");
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(imageFolderPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(imageFolderPath,true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is duplicate of 
[Is it possible to store images in xamarin sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361964/is-it-possible-to-store-images-in-xamarin-sqlite)

and probably 
[How to store image in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database) can help you.

Comment: these all are about only android i want to know about xamarin forms cross platform. Any solution please help

Comment: Did you try these?? Because db is same SQlite so it will store images in blob only.

Comment: this is in java and they are doing in android activities. I am not getting in xamarin forms where to do it means by dependency i have to do or simply in portable class library. And i have to do it in c#

Comment: ok letme check and if i could find something i ll let u know

Comment: Thanks, Please help me if you can

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22982/saving-image-in-sqlite-database 
Hey according to discussion on their forums you could go for saving the image on file syatem and store its path in database that will be easy approach and also it ll wrk fine. Do you wanna try this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853301/save-and-load-image-sqlite-c-sharp check this out...

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yeah i already checked this discussion but there is no example how to do ??

Comment: That is simple you need to pick the path of file from where you are picking the image and save that path in database. Check this out for your reference: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/pick_image/

Comment: Thanks a lot @preetika, i will try this

Comment: Its my pleasure !! Kindly vote for answer if it helped you and accept it if it works for you.