# Writing Image to Sqlite after Camera_Request

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Looking for some help.  I am trying to add strings of information to a sqlite database which is working OK.  But now I want to add an image captured from the camera.  I have setup the DB with a new blob entry. 
Thing I cant understand is passing the byte image from the oncallistener of "add photo" to the oncallistener of the "Add to DB" button. The add DB button is where I write to the database.

Any ideas?

```js
add_save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      
      add_db_bsdate = add_bsdate.getText().toString();
      add_db_report = add_report.getText().toString();
   add_db_longt = add_longt.getText().toString();
   add_db_lat = add_lat.getText().toString();
   add_db_type = add_type.getSelectedItem().toString();
   add_db_city = add_city.getSelectedItem().toString();

   
   
   
     byte[] imageInByte = null;
  dbHandler.Add_Blackspot(new Blackspot(add_db_bsdate, add_db_report, add_db_longt, add_db_lat, add_db_type, add_db_city, imageInByte));  //imageInByte declared from ActivityResult
      Toast_msg = "Data inserted successfully";
      Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
      Reset_Text();

      //}

     }
 });
    }
```

My ActivityResults that returns imageInByte.  How do I write this to DB above?

```js
    @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
   return;

  switch (requestCode) {
  case CAMERA_REQUEST:
      


     Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    

   if (extras != null) {
    
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
          //Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
          
    Bitmap yourImage = extras.getParcelable("data");
    // convert bitmap to byte
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(yourImage);
    
    // Inserting Contacts
    //dbHandler.Add_Blackspot(new Blackspot(add_db_bsdate, add_db_report, add_db_longt, add_db_lat, add_db_type, add_db_city));
    //dbHandler.Add_Blackspot(new Blackspot("Android", imageInByte));
    //Intent i = new Intent(Add_Update_User.this,
      //Add_Update_User.class);
    //startActivity(i);
    //finish();
     //callCamera();
   
   }
   
   break;
```

Comment: You can save the image path url into database and retrieve it whenever you need.

Comment: I would prefer store the image in the database as it will not be a local app.

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database