# BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream) return null in a BLOB image SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, null, blob, inputstream

I have a few days with the same problem, I am making an application in which I need to save images in `SQLite`, until then good.
The problem is when trying to recover, attached my code:

```
recuperarImagen = db.rawQuery("SELECT fotoPerfil FROM perfil WHERE _id = 1", null);

if(recuperarImagen.moveToFirst()){
    byte[] blob = recuperarImagen.getBlob(0);
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    imagenPersonal.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

- `recuperarImagen` is the Cursor
- `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)` returns `null`

To store the image I use this method:

> public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();

}
```

If anyone can help I would be very grateful,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to add how you're storing the blob in the first place. Also, if this is on Android, which I am assuming, tag it as such please.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database