# how can i upload image from phone memory to android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am trying to develop an android app in which there is an option to upload image from phone memory and then it will display in a list View with some heading given by user.
I have created layout of it but I don't know how to implement this concept.
I used one EditText and a Button for uploading file in LinearLayout and use ListView in another activity to display images

Comment: post what you have tried? else you get automatically downvote..

Comment: I'm wondering if you even looked for an answer before posting this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database

Comment: I used one EditText and a Button for uploading file in LinearLayout and use ListView in another activity to display images. @ranjith

Comment: @PravalSharma edit your question..I am also get many downvotes in my qtn by this mistake.

Comment: okk i will explain my layout in ques @ranjith