# Using ViewBinder, SimpleCursorAdapter, SQLite, to show pictures taken by a camera on ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

What this program is supposed to do is when it starts up, and when the camera icon on the activity bar is clicked, a camera will be opened and if a user takes a photo and oks to save it the picture will be saved in the database and the photo will be shown on the main page as a thumbnail in a ListView immediately after the camera instance is gone.

However so far I have been getting a SQLiteException saying "unknown error (code 0): INTEGER data in nativeGetBlob".

Each time before I run my code after doing some debugging I would remove my database entirely so it would have a fresh start. And in my database actually the storing process was apparently ok because I use adb to check my database and my command prompt shows that the table has two columns, first one is the _id and the second is the images column, the pictures are stored in the form of .PNG. as byte[], and the ids are autoincremented.

I have succeeded getting just one test image to show as a simple ImageView (with the same SQLite storing code) but when I attempt to show it on a ListView, using ViewBinder and SimpleCursorAdapter I am getting the SQLiteException. I have read many other questions here and try their solutions for the whole day already but still stuck. Any expert out there who knows how to debug my program?

Here are my codes so far:

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("images.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists tb (  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, image blob)");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        //dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            //Calling dispatchTakePictureIntent to start the camera activity
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            /*Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ImageView thumb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb1);
            thumb1.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);*/
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageTaken = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            //calculate how many bytes our image consists of.
           /* int bytes = imageTaken.getByteCount();
            //or we can calculate bytes this way. Use a different value than 4 if you don't use 32bit images.
            //int bytes = b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()*4;

            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
            imageTaken.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

            byte[] toValuesPut = buffer.array(); //Get the underlying array containing the data.
            */
           byte[] toValuesPut = this.getBytes(imageTaken);
            values.put("image", toValuesPut);
            db.insert("tb", null, values);
            getImage();

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            db.close();
        }

    }

    protected void getImage(){
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from tb", null);
        if (c.moveToNext()){
            //byte[] image = c.getBlob(0);
            //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
            //ImageView thumb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb1);
            // thumb1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sampleListView);
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.photos, c, new String[] { "_id", "image" }, new int[]{R.id.col1, R.id.col2});

            SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder viewBinder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor,
                                            int columnIndex) {
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
                    byte[] byteArr = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
                    image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, byteArr.length));
                    return true;
                }
            };
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.editimage);
            viewBinder.setViewValue(image, c, c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            adapter.setViewBinder(viewBinder);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="793dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.23" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:width="50dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"

        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/col2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:width="150dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/editimage"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="ClickHandlerForEditImage"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"/>

</TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/camera"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sampleListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#CCCCCC"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

photos.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/thumb2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>
```

Logcat:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): INTEGER data in nativeGetBlob
            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(Native Method)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:403)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
            at hiew1.is2.byuh.edu.mydailyselfie.MainActivity$1.setViewValue(MainActivity.java:133)
            at hiew1.is2.byuh.edu.mydailyselfie.MainActivity.getImage(MainActivity.java:139)
            at hiew1.is2.byuh.edu.mydailyselfie.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:108)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3573)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3620)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try following this example, without using ViewBinder and SimpleCursorAdapter. Just use the method bindblob() and a Cursor:

[How to store image in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database)