# How to store large Data in application?

Tags: android, image, sqlite, out-of-memory

I want to make image backup through my `Application` what is the best way for storing large amount of data . I tried to save image in `sqlite database` it worked fine for small amount of data in case of large amount it shows `MemoryOutOfBoundExceptions` after increasing the Heep `size(android:largeHeap="true")`.
please help me guys .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Storing Large data in `Application` you have to store it `DataBase` so it will speed up your Application and you have no `Exception` produce like `OutOfMemoryException` in your `Application`.

Comment: m tyied to store in DataBase by converting image into bitmap than compress() But this process also give me OutOfMemoryException

Comment: @xyzrety visit this link it will help you to store `Image` in `DataBase`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database

Comment: @xyzrety you have go  through `DataBase` it is right Approch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115627/discussion-between-xyz-rety-and-ironman).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save only image or any file try to save only path of that file in database.After that you can get file path by normal SQL query and access file from file path.

Answer (score 0):

You don't store images in databases, that makes the database huge and slows it down.  Store the images to disk and store the path to the file in the database.  This will make the database a lot lighter and faster.

If you're developing for Android, i'd also recommend using something like Picasso, Fresco or Glide to display your images too.  They cache the image and use memory efficiently when doing operations like scaling images.