# Find image location on HDD, then insert that into SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to read(view) some images from my HDD then insert them in SQLite database and retrieve them from SQLite.

There is 2 problems I am facing, **first problem** is images graphic are very bad that's why I can see the images, **second problem** is I don't know where the file directory.

After spending hours and hours I found the directory from debug mode but it's doesn't seem locate in my HDD.

I got this below image location in debug mode but I can't figure it out where is in my HDD. uri: "content://media/external/images/media/47"

Comment: Images aren't good data to put in BLOB format. Why do you need this feature?

Comment: HI it is part of my project requirement, please help me out if you can.

Comment: If you browse the actual device storage (try installing a file browser app), where is the image stored? Alternatively, that is a ContentProvider URI, so have you tried querying that?

Comment: Emulator shouldn't matter. It *emulates* physical hardware such as disk. Please don't add code into the comments. [Edit] the question instead

Comment: I'm using emulator and yes I have tried some method but end up this path
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/ IMG_2017073643.jpg that I can't figure it out

Comment: where can I show code please?

Comment: what is the benefit to edit the question

Comment: The benefit is that we can see what you are doing... Okay, you have a file path! So, open / read it, and dump it into a Sqlite database. If you have problems with that, ask a *specific question* related to that. Such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database