# how to add image to sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using **SQLite** DataBase to store various variables data in my Android App. Using a ImagePicker, I am taking **Image** from gallery to **ImageHolder** and I need to store those into database.

I have created the **column_4_image**. Not able to figure out, How to store Image to database. Found similar question, but they were not answering when will I get errors, if my Image size is above certain limit. How can I know the device limit image pushing limits.

This is my `SQLiteHelper.java` class

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+" ("
                +Table_Column_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                +Table_Column_1_Name+" VARCHAR, "
                +Table_Column_2_PhoneNumber +" VARCHAR, "
                +Table_Column_3_Date+" VARCHAR,"
                +Table_Column_4_Image+" BLOB)";
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }
```

This is my `addDataActivity.java` class

```
public void SQLiteTableBuild(){
    sqLiteDatabaseObj.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            +SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+"(id "
            +SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_ID +" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
            +SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_1_Name+" VARCHAR, "
            +SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_2_PhoneNumber+" VARCHAR, "
            +SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_3_Date+" VARCHAR, "
            +SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_4_Image+" BLOB);");
}


public void InsertDataIntoSQLiteDatabase(){
    if(EditTextEmptyHold){
        SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder = "INSERT INTO "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+" (name,phone_number,date) VALUES('"+NameHolder+"', '"+NumberHolder+"','"+DateHolder+"');";
        sqLiteDatabaseObj.execSQL(SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder);
        sqLiteDatabaseObj.close();
    } //else data insertion failed
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store image in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database)

Comment: Check your create table statement, you are missing a space before BLOB. Here Table_Column_4_Image+"BLOB)";

Comment: SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_4_Image+"BLOB); change it to SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_4_Image+" BLOB);")

Comment: Ok guyz I just want to know how can I take image on button click and put it in sqlite db by converting it, in my code.
I have seen many questions but I'm not able to link it to my problem

Comment: instead of storing images in db, just save the image in your device, and in your db, save the location with filename in some column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Extract the image from the source file as a byte array.

2) Prepare a ContentValues instance and populate it, then use the `insert` method e.g :-

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_1_Name,NameHolder);
    cv.put(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_2_PhoneNumber,NumberHolder);
    cv.put(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_3_Date,DateHolder);
    cv.put(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_4_Image,your_image_as_a_byte_array);
    long result = sqLiteDatabaseObj.insert(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
```

To retrieve get the byte array using `getBlob` method e.g.

```
    byte[] myimageasbytearray = cursor.getBlob(cusror.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_4_Image));
```

However, storing images themselves is not recommended.

- A Cursor Window is limited to 2Mb thus images will greatly increase the chance of errors occurring due to this limitation.
- Disk access(IO) will be significantly greater.
- Data will fill the cache(s) thus again likely further increasing Disk access(IO).

The recommended way is to store the path to the image in the database.