# Storing an image in a SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my Doctor.java file. The app is such that when the user comes to this page via a list view he will automatically see the list of doctors. Now I have populated the database with the doctors as below but it would be really good if i can also put the images of the doctors too. I have already stored the images of each doctor in the drawable folder but I have no idea how to put them in the database. Can someone help me please.
Doctor.java

```
package net.limb.healthservices;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by purus on 03-Feb-18.
 */

public class Doctor extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
SQLiteDatabase db;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor);
    TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    String doc= getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
    String authentication= getIntent().getStringExtra("auth");
    textView.setText(doc);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("DoctorDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor(Name VARCHAR,degree VARCHAR,address VARCHAR,phnumber VARCHAR,dept VARCHAR);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Sujoy Khan','MBBS,MRCP,DRCPATH,FRCPATH,FRCP','58, Canal Circular Road, Kadapara, Apollo Gleneagles Hospital Limited, Kolkata,West Bengal 700054.','18605001066','Allergist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Allergy & Asthma Treatment Centre',' ','155A, A. J. C. Bose Road, Acharya Jagadish Chandra Bose Rd, Entally, Kolkata, West Bengal 700014','9874555339','Allergist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Amitava Chakraborty','MBBS,MRCP,DRCPATH,FRCPATH,FRCP','207, Netaji Subhash Chandra Bose Rd, Bansdroni, Kolkata, West Bengal 700040.','03324815741','Allergist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Ranjan Shrivatava','MBBS, Diploma in Cardiology, MD - Medicine','Nazrul Islam Avenue, VIP Road, Landmark: Opposite Haldiram, Kolkata','+91 33794 14541','Cardiologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Arindam Pande','MBBS, MD - General Medicine, DM - Cardiology, FACC, FESC','59, Kalicharan Ghosh Road, Sinthee, Landmark: Near Sinthee Police Station, Kolkata','+913379415380','Cardiologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Ranjan Kumar Sharma','MBBS, DNB (Cardiology), MD - General Medicine, DM - Cardiology, DIP Card','73 & 81B , Bagmari Road,, Landmark: Near Ultadanga Hudco Stop, Kolkata','+913379415380','Cardiologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Gautam Banerjee','MBBS,MRCP,DRCPATH,FRCPATH,FRCP','58, Canal Circular Road, Kadapara, Apollo Gleneagles Hospital Limited, Kolkata,West Bengal 700054.','033 2555 6244','Dermatologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Sabyasachi Mazumdar','MD - Dermatology, MBBS','FA-53, Ramakrishna Nagar, Laskarpur, Garia BT. Landmark: Kavi Nazrul Metro    Station., Kolkata','+91 33794 15380','Dermatologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr Sayantani Chakraborty','MBBS, MD - Dermatology','DA 8, Sector 1, Landmark: Near Katerpillar Cafe, Kolkata','+91 33794 14551','Dermatologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Supratik Bhattacharyya','MBBS, MD - Medicine, MRCP (UK), FACP (USA), MS - Endocrinology & Diabetes','1st floor, Street Number 124, BG Block, Action Area B, Landmark: Near Rajarhat,  Kolkata','+91 33794 14411','Endocrinologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Kaushik Pandit','MBBS, MD - General Medicine, DNB - General Medicine, DM - Endocrinology','2/7, 1st Floor, Vasundara Building, Minto Park, Landmark: Beside Central Plaza    Building, Kolkata','+91 33794 14541','Endocrinologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Rachna Mazumder','MBBS, MD - General Medicine, DM - Endocrinology, MRCP (UK), FRCP - Internal    Medicine','30/B Prince Anwar Shah Road., Landmark: Opposite To ICICI Bank., Kolkata','+91 33794 14207','Endocrinologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Sanjoy Mandal','MBBS, MS - General Surgery, DNB - General Surgery, MNAMS - General Surgery','173, CB Block, Sector-1, Landmark: Opposite CB Block Community Center & Near    Tank Number 2, Kolkata','+91 33794 14551','Gastroenterologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Mahesh Kumar Goenka','MBBS, MD - Medicine, DM - Gastroenterology, FACG, FASGE','58, Canal Circular Lane, Kadapara, Kankurgachi, Landmark: Near Maniskar Mall,    Kolkata','+91 33794 15093','Gastroenterologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Vijay Kumar Rai','DM - Gastroenterology, MD - Internal Medicine, MBBS','P122, 1st Floor, CIT Road, Landmark: Next To Goli Vadapaav & Near Pantaloons,    Kolkata','+91 33794 14207','Gastroenterologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Avijit Das','DM - Neurology, Post Doctoral Fellowship in Neurological Rehabilitation, MD -   General Medicine, MBBS','230, Barakhola Lane, Purba Jadavpur, Landmark: Behind Metro Cash & Carry,  Kolkata','+91 33794 14258','Neurologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. S K Somani','MBBS, Diploma in Tropical Medicine Health, MD - General Medicine, DM -  Neurology','21, Prannath Pandit Street, Bhawanipur, Kolkata','+91 33794 14541','Neurologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Abhijit Chatterjee','MBBS,MD,DM (NEURO)','60, Motilal Nehru Road, Lansdowne, Kolkata, West Bengal 700029','033 2475 0334','Neurologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Pallavi Daga','MBBS, MS - Obstetrics & Gynaecology, MRCOG','78, Sambhunath Pandit Street, Landmark: Behind Gol Mandir and Opposite to    Rabindra Sadan Metro Station, Kolkata','+91 33794 15286 ','OBGYN');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Subidita Chatterjee','MBBS, DGO, DNB - Obstetrics & Gynecology','CF-391, Sector 1, Landmark: Near Purpo Bhavan., Kolkata','+91 33794 14551','OBGYN');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Sharmishtha Patra','MBBS, MS - Obstetrics & Gynaecology, MRCOG, FICRS','BH - 36, Sector - 2, Near Kathgola Stop, Salt Lake, Landmark: Opposite Bank of   Baroda., Kolkata','+91 33794 15093','OBGYN');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Tamohan Chaudhuri','MBBS, MD - Oncology, Diploma in Radio Therapy','House No. 7/14,Purbachal Complex,Sector-3, Kolkata','+91 33794 14551','Oncologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Prasenjit Chatterjee','MBBS, Diploma in Radio Therapy, DNB - Radiation Oncology, MD Radiation    Oncology','8/5, Alipore Road, Landmark: Near Natural Library, Alipore Zoo & Visa House,     Kolkata','+91 33794 15093','Oncologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Indranil Ghosh','DM - Oncology, MD - Pediatrics, MBBS','58, Canal Circular Road, Phulbagan, Kolkata','+91 33794 14551','Oncologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Siddhartha Ghosh','MBBS, MS - Ophthalmology','48/1F, Leela Roy Sarani, Ballygunge, Landmark: Near Dover Terrace, Kolkata','+91 33794 15093','Opthalmologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Pradeep Kumar Saraf','MBBS, MS - Ophthalmology, Fellowship in Vitreoretinal Surgery','51/1A, Near Motor Vehicles & Lansdown Padopukur, Sarat Bose Road. Landmark: Opp. to Health Point Nursing Home, Kolkata','+91 33794 14541','Opthalmologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Somnath Ghosh','Post Graduate Diploma in Ophthalmology, MBBS','P 40/A, Block D., Landmark: Near Bangur Boys School, Kolkata','+91 33794 15286','Opthalmologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Abhijit Sarkar','MBBS, MRCPCH (UK), Member of the Royal College of Paediatrics and Child Health (MRCPCH, London, Glasgow or Edinburgh), Diploma in Child Health (DCH), Diploma in Child Health (DCH)','AD-145, Sector-1, Landmark: Near Tank 4, Kolkata','+91 33794 14322','Pediatrician');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Sumita Saha','MBBS, Diploma in Child Health (DCH - UK), MRCPCH (UK)','730, Eastern Metropolitan Bypass, Anandapur, Landmark: Near Kolkata    International School & Near Ruby Hospital, Kolkata','+91 33794 15093 ','Pediatrician');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Ajit Kumar Verma','MBBS, Diploma in Child Health (DCH)','Shop #F20, NBCC Shoping Center, Landmark: Near New Town Bus Stand., Landmark:   New Town Bus Depot, Kolkata','+91 33794 14258','Pediatrician');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Indranil Saha','MBBS, MD - Psychiatry, DPM (Psychiatry)','P77, Green View, Baishnab Ghata Patuli, Kolkata 700084, Landmark: Opposite BRWS (Outdoor) Hospital, Kolkata','+91 33794 15093','Psychologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Prathama Chaudhuri','MBBS, MD - Psychiatry, DNB - Psychiatry, Fellowship in Child and Adolescent     Psychiatry, Certificate in Hypnotherapy','GD-347, GD Block, Sector III, Kolkata, Landmark: Near G D Community Hall, Kolkata','+91 33794 14298','Psychologist');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO doctor VALUES('Dr. Amitabha Mukerji','MBBS, MD - Psychiatry','256, Block-B, Landmark: Near Lake Town Nursing Home, Kolkata','+91 33794 14258','Psychologist');");

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



}
}
```

This is my doctor.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/docdefault" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="time" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database

Comment: You can also store the `Base64` string of the image in string column

Comment: is this an online app? well storing images in a database is not a good practice. What you can do is, reference the file location of the images in the database. For example, if it's an online app, there will be a database with a table named doctors which has a column called picture, where the url of the image file is kept, and when you want to display the image just fetch the image from the URL.

Comment: Storing images in a database is NEVER a good idea. Much better to save the image **paths** only.

Comment: I am trying to store the paths of the image. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different approaches to store images in a database.
The most popular ones would probably be formatting the image into a base64 String and saving the String, or converting it into a byte-array and storing it as a blob.

An example of converting an image drawable to a base64 String:

```
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}


BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image);
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
encodedImage = encodeToBase64(bitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100); //Make sure you choose the correct CompressFormat for your image eg. PNG, JPG, ...
```