# Android: Byte array for the image is null when stored in SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am very close to having this work. I get a picture from the camera and store it in my SQLite database. However when I store it, I get this error. The byte array for the image is null when stored. Why? How can I fix it?

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.psa.stepbystep, PID: 16363
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>                         at com.example.psa.stepbystep.Walk.writeToParcel(Walk.java:161)
>                         at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1730)
>                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1636)
>                         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:777)
>                         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1506)

Walk Activity contains Parcel

```
public Walk(Parcel in) {
        this._photo = new byte[in.readInt()];
        in.readByteArray(_photo);
    }

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(_photo.length);
        dest.writeByteArray(_photo);
    }
```

WalkPhoto has this to convert

```
 //Convert from bitmap to byte array
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    //Convert from byte array to bitmap
    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
```

WalkPhoto also has this to store the image in the database

```
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ImageView imageview = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

            //Bitmap to bytes for database
            byte[] photo = getBytes(imageBitmap);

             DatabaseHandler mydb = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

            Walk walk = new Walk(photo);

            mydb.addWalk(walk);
}
```

Comment: You can use "blob" to store image as mention in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357943/5455940

Comment: @AbuBakarSiddiq what is "insertStatement_logo" in that example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "blob" to store image as mention in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357943/5455940

In above post "insertStatement_logo" is instance of `SQLiteStatement` class.
`SQLiteStatement` is subclass of `SQLiteProgram` class.

See links for reference. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html