# How i can fetch images from mysql and display it in recyclerview using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

I am fetching record and pictures from mysql e.g I am fetching teacher information and there pictures. Every thing is working fine instead of fetching images. How i can fetch images and place them to recyclerview. I am using retrofit. 
In adapter

> onBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tName.setText(subjects.get(position).getName());
    holder.tEmail.setText(subjects.get(position).getEmail());
    holder.tRoom.setText(subjects.get(position).getPhoneNum());
    Glide.with(holder.tPicture.getContext()).load(subjects.get(position)).into(holder.tPicture);
```

And here is mainActivity response

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Teache_GetterAndSetter>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Teache_GetterAndSetter>> call, Response<List<Teache_GetterAndSetter>> response) {
            subjects = response.body();
            adapter =new TeacherAdapterApi(subjects,getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

> Note: Php script is working file.
>   Here is php response:
>   [{"T_id":39,"T_u_name":"Adnan","T_f_name":"fahad","T_email":"mirzafahadi1122@gmail.com","T_num":"03225898717","T_m_name":"pakistan","T_pic":"a.png","room":"G-001"}]

The problem is i am not getting images from mysql.

Comment: You can't just return an image. You need to store the image in some place like S3 for example and return the path to the image store there.

Comment: use piccso to display your image

Comment: How i can use picasso kindly elaborate? I am not mush expert

Comment: @jonathanrz how i can store it in S3??

Comment: have a look over this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357943/6672577

Comment: what is the image full path ??

Comment: Inside `Glide` this part of code: `.load(subjects.get(position)` - shouldn't be here like `load(subjects.get(position).getImage())` or whatever you name it in model or `pojo` class? On that way you are getting the object of `subject` not image url.

Comment: Glide.with(context).load(subjects.get(position).getPic()).into(holder.tPicture); 
 Still not working

Comment: @sushildlh    Path is mention in Note ("T_pic":"a.png") And the full path is (Project\Admin\teacher register\images)

Comment: I got it. Thanks for cooperation.