# How do i start converting my image string file into a byte array so I can store it in my data base?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So this is the image file I got. Now, how do I convert this picturePath into a byte array so I can store it in my database?

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    ivFoodPicture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

Comment: You can also ask yourself  *"How to store a image in database on Android ?"*. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668) will then help you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the Bitmap from the URI.

Pseduo:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
```

And then to get the byte[] you can do:

```
   private byte[] toByteArray(@NonNull Bitmap bm)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

But do take care as these could Out Of Memory error with large files. Even base64Encoding these into a String can cause OOM.

Comment: `You would need to get the Bitmap from the URI.` Not at all. And memory problems all around. Just load the jpg file in a byte array instead. In this way you can handle any file in the same way too.

Comment: "Even base64 encoding" -- base64 encoding takes more memory than just a byte array, so would be more likely to cause an OOM error.

Comment: would i need to make the bitmap as an instance variable so I can pass it through the `toByteArray`? And how would i use this function inside my code?