# Null pointer exception while loading images from gallery.

Tags: android

This is my code to get the images from Gallery. It is giving a null pointer exception and crashing. I am testing the code on the device itself and it crashes once I chose an image in the gallery. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
                     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreatePod.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Select") .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   Intent gallIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                    gallIntent.setType("image/*"); 
                                    startActivityForResult(gallIntent, 10);
                               }
                        })




protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){


     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);






        switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                   Bitmap b = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                   imgView.setImageBitmap(b);

                String timestamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
                   MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, timestamp, timestamp);
                HttpResponse httpResponse;
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);

            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            int f = 0;
            String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, f);
```

Comment: 1. paste the stacktrace of exception. Launch your app in debug mode. And look at the stacktrace.

Comment: I did. I get Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); extras as null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using

```
Bitmap b = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");   
imgView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Use the following lines of code:

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData(); 
Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
imgView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

I changed your code and ran, it is working for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that the photo is not returned in extras.  Its Uri is in getData().

Try this code instead:

```
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri bitmapUri = data.getData();

                try {

                    Bitmap b = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), bitmapUri);
                    mImgView.setImageBitmap(b);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // ... etc ...
                break;
            }
    }
```

Also, I think you are doing too much around AlertDialogBuilder.  I just did this:

```
public void myClickHandler(View clickTarget) {
    Intent gallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    gallIntent.setType("image/*");
    gallIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(gallIntent, 10);
}
```