# uploading image on an external server

Tags: java, android, blob

I am able to take picture in my android application and i am able to get its path too. Now after clicking that picture, i have created a button called "upload image" which when clicked should upload that image as a BLOB object in an external database hosted online.

I am unable to do that. Can anyone help me in this.

This is the code i am taking for getting the path of the image to be uploaded:

```
String filePath =
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/your_image_name.jpeg";
File file = new File(filePath);
Uri output = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a image to the server, it is highly recommended to use web services. This is explained with a neat example in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643474/uploading-an-image-from-android-to-mysql-database) link . Recommend you to refer the steps provided in the link to proceed working on your project.