# Where should i use OnActivityResult here?

Tags: android

When i do debug it didnt go to try block than catch block , this is my code please help me!

```
public void onClick(View v) {
               try {

                 path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/audio_meena.AMR";
                 File newFile = new File(path);
                 Uri uri =Uri.fromFile(newFile);
                 Intent audioIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
                 startActivityForResult(audioIntent, RQS_RECORDING);
                 mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                 mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                 mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                 FileDescriptor PATH_NAME = null;
                 mr.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
}
        });
```

Comment: What actually you want to do..Not getting clear idea from the Quetion??Please be more Specific!!

Comment: any error or exceptions you getting

Comment: Might be you havent set onClickListener on any view, so this block is not getting invoked at all.

Comment: check this [how to pick a image from gallery (SD Card) for my app in android?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

this may give you the clear picture.

Comment: please post the code that is Above this code..it's require to see the Listener you have used

Answer (score 0):

either set the "onClick" attribute to the view you wish (via the layout) , or find it right after the "setContentView" using "findViewById" and then use "setOnClickListener" for the view .

about "OnActivityResult", you need to put it in the activity itself as a stand alone method .

Comment: Yeah , i have used Listener for all kinda buttons like record, play, stop and save. I am getting clearly output and could i able to record audio . But it doesnt save in SD card since path is not identified . What do i wanna do ?

Comment: maybe you are missing a permission to write to the external storage ?

Comment: I have requested this in Manifest.xml..<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: not sure i understand the problem . does it crash? can you please show your updated code and the log ?