# Android Bitmap Passing issue

Tags: android, bitmap

Is there another way to pass bitmap between activities in fast way

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Second.class)
i.putExtra("Image", bitmap);
startActivity(i)
```

My Activity slows down when I pass bitmap in android.

Comment: Pass bitmap by Uri

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12217596/1099716

Comment: Thanks  @Access Denied its work for me :)

Comment: @AccessDenied is it possible to convert image uri into base64 String without saving image bitmap??

Comment: Maybe you want to escape uri? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want.You can create a class which named ImageManager add a static variable like sBitmap,you can set value in ActivityA and then use it by ImageManager.sBitmap in ActivityB.