# Android Dynamic ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I am making a custom layout in which I want to add the image view dynamically from the gallery. But as soon as I pick the image from the gallery , I got force close. I am unable to get what is the error behind the same.

Here is my code..

```
public class Dynamic extends Activity {
int i;
ImageView[] img_items;
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
LinearLayout imageLayout;
Button btn;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dynamic_load);

    imageLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.image_layout);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ADD);
    img_items = new ImageView[values.size()];

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            values.add("AA");

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        /*ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));*/


        //Creating the image layouts dynamically
        for( i=0;i<values.size();i++){

            img_items[i] = new ImageView(Dynamic.this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
            img_items[i].setLayoutParams(params);

        }

        img_items[i].setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        imageLayout.addView(img_items[i]);


    }
}
}
```

LOG CAT

```
10-05 16:52:03.422: D/AndroidRuntime(451): Shutting down VM
10-05 16:52:03.422: W/dalvikvm(451): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/1 }} to activity {com.example.dynamicloading/com.example.dynamicloading.Dynamic}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.example.dynamicloading.Dynamic.onActivityResult(Dynamic.java:81)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
10-05 16:52:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  ... 11 more
10-05 16:57:04.140: I/Process(451): Sending signal. PID: 451 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Always add your logcat error report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to decrease the `i` value by one as the `i` was increment in for loop for example you have iterate for `5` time so the for loop will be iterate `5` time starting with `0` and ending with the `4` but at that time the `i` value was incremented first then it will check the 2 expression whether the length and for `i` at that time `i` value and `values.size()` are same so it terminate the for loop execute rest of code

**Edited**

```
if(i==values.size() && i>0)
   i--;

img_items[i].setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
imageLayout.addView(img_items[i]);
```

and one more thing you need set `i=0` every time when you in `onActivityResult()` other wise you always getting `i` last value

Comment: Pratik thanks but your english is less understandable. Please dont feel bad. I am saying this to improve as a bro.

Comment: for loop executes the body first and then increments the value of index. so for me the above working flow is not correct.. if you do i--; then value will change to -1 in its first execution and the array index cannot be -1.

Comment: and yes another answer also correct you need to initialize the img_items with its size

Comment: Same problem exists.. No change

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the array img_items in onCreate :

```
img_items = new ImageView[values.size()];
```

At this point values.size() is "zero".

You should do this intialization before the for loop in onActivityResult:

```
    img_items = new ImageView[values.size()];
    for( i=0;i<values.size();i++){
    ...
```

Comment: Same problem exists.. No change

Answer (score 0):

After Seeing code i can just say that when you initializing the array of ImageView with values.size()

```
img_items = new ImageView[values.size()];
```

at that time the "values" Arraylist have 0 size and hence the ImageView array is also of 0 size and then you are putting an ImageView in an array of size 0 in onActivityResult().

```
img_items[i] = new ImageView(Dynamic.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which loads multiple images from image intent. I took help from [How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)

```
  Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                               selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
            {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            ImageView img_items = new ImageView(AnimatedPopupActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
            img_items.setLayoutParams(params);

            img_items.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            imageLayout.addView(img_items);



            cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity class..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout mainLinearLayout;
    Button button;
      Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                openGallery();
            }
        });
    }


    private void openGallery()
    {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, intent);


        if (requestCode == 1)
        {
            if (intent != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK)
            {             

                  Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();

                  String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                  cursor.moveToFirst();
                  int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                  String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                  cursor.close();

                  if(bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled())
                  {
                      bmp = null;               
                  }

                  bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                 imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
                 imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

                 mainLinearLayout.addView(imageView,lp);


            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Status:", "Photopicker canceled");           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are u giving me alternates.. your scenario is totally different, you are just doing it for one image view,. I just want to add dynamically to any no. of image views.