# Android: can't find startActivityForResult request_code

Tags: android

I want to set an `imageview` and let the user to set his own image, i found how to do that on another question, but all the answers contains attribute for `startActivityForResult` function like `PICK_IMAGE` or `SELECT_IMAGE` or `ACTIVITY_IMAGE_SELECTOR` but my eclipse says that those are not defined , why ?

## Edit

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Comment: @p i tried and still the same error, i update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare this variable on top :

```
int PICK_IMAGE = 101;
```

This is just a request code to match on your activity result.

**References :**

[Pick Image Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5086706/556975)

[How To Pick Image From Gallery in Android App](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/)

Thanks.

Comment: and how can i find the integer value for all the attributes ?

Comment: it works, really thanks you , i will accept your answer, but please would you tell me how to find all the integer values for attribues ?

Comment: and why my eclipse doesn't recognize `PICK_IMAGE` it self?

Comment: @FernadoMargin there is no standard values for this. You can define any value for that. Adding one reference link with this for full example.

Comment: sorry my english is bad, did u ask me to give you my code ?, i already did

Comment: @FernadoMargin check the references I added, that will clear all your doubts about it with complete example.

Answer (score 1):

in your MainActvity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
   static MainActivity instance= null;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       instance = this; 
    }
}
```

and in your class make:

```
MainActivity.instance.startActivityForResult(intent,request_code);
```