# Android - Is it possible to make a post on Facebook wall using an image from sdcard but not URL?

Tags: android, facebook, url, post, sd-card

Could anyone help me, please?
I'd like to make a post on Facebook and put an image from a sdcard. If I use URL - everything is ok. But what should I do to upload a picture from the sdcard? Maybe I need to download it first on facebook like a photo and then get it url? But how can I then get url of recently uploaded photo?

```
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", title);
        postParams
                .putString("caption", caption);
        postParams.putString("description", description);
        postParams
                .putString("link",
                        "https://");
        postParams
                .putString(
                        "picture",
                        "https://");


        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                if (response.getError() == null) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("Facebook Error",
                                "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
                HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to put the image in the parameters to post:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", message);
params.putByteArray("picture", data);
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");

AsyncFacebookRunner runner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebookHandler.facebook);
runner.request(null, params, "POST", new RequestListener() {
public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {}
public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {    }
public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {}
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {    }
public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
returnHandler().sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
}, null);
```

Where bmp is a `Bitmap`, get it from where ever you like.

Comment: This solution is for the old SDK, it might not work with the new Facebook SDK 3. Just chiming in with that tip.

Comment: @Machinarius: It's not using the old SDK per-se, but just an older REST API. _@Demonick_: This should not really be used for new applications. That being said, apparently it still works but can't confirm seeing the wiser choice was to switch to a newer API as far as my app was concerned. [Read more on it here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the main problem is that it should look so http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/205645_4415760508294_181051897_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
byte[] data = null;

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmpImageGallery.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle postImgGallery = new Bundle();

// ADD THE PHOTO DATA TO THE BUNDLE
postImgGallery.putByteArray("photo", data);
```

Note: The `bmpImageGallery` in the code above is an instance of a Bitmap. The instance holds the Image selected either from a Gallery application or a Camera application. You will naturally have to adapt a few things seeing that the question was only about uploading an image. However, if you do need help on selecting an Image, this might be of help: [How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2507898/450534)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the main problem is that it should look so http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/205645_4415760508294_181051897_n.jpg