# android select image from sdcard

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview

I have an `imageview` with a default image, I want when user click the imageview to open an image selector then he selects his image from sdcard then the image is being on the imageview,

this is my imageview

#### xml

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/iv_undefinedImage"
            android:src="@drawable/undefinedimage" />
```

#### Java

```
ImageView iv ;
iv_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_signup_image);
        iv_image.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.iv_signup_image:
break;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to select the image from the gallery onclick of the imageview and that selected image is set again on the Imageview ? Is this what you want ?

Comment: Why in the world you will go for writing an answer for a repetitive question which is already been asked and voted by 100's of user.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

Comment: @MKJParekh yes it is the write answer who help me, sorry i am not good at searching

Comment: Let me try to tell you the "Secrets of Searching" ... first of all have a problem in mind.. get ready to ask question on Stackoverflow for that.. when you start writing question.. you will have to write title for that.. make one title... now STOP... stop right there.. copy the title you wrote and paste in google search box.... I hope this will help you next time.!!

Comment: I tried your way and google give me answers but not exactly the title i used, why please? and in this case can i ask here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals("mounted")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(
            intent,
            "Select Picture:"),
        requestCode);
}
```

and to handle the callback

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    Bitmap photo = getPreview(selectedImagePath);
}


public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(proj[0]);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}

public Bitmap getPreview(String fileName) {
    File image = new File(fileName);

    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1)) {
        return null;
    }
    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
        : bounds.outWidth;
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / 64;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), opts);
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: what is `R.string.select_pic` and what is `request code ` ?

Comment: your answer help to open the sdcard to select image, now how to set the image to my imageview?

Comment: sorry that string was just a header for the chooser and requestCode is used when multiple intents fire onActivityResult(), its just a differentiator.

Comment: what is getPath? what is getPreview?

Comment: now added everything i hope

Answer (score 1):

You will need to load the image from the SDCard to a Bitmap, and then set the bitmap image to the ImageView:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/file.png");
iv_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

As stated by `yahya`, you could also create a drawable out of the SDCard image file and then set the image drawable:

```
iv_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("/path/to/file.png"));
```

You should also make sure that in your Manifest you include a permission to read (/write) to the SDCard.

Comment: Or as a drawable... iv_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("/path/to/file.png"));

Comment: Somepoint this week I shall run a few tests to see which is more efficient xD

Comment: I don't know the path of the image, the user will select any image from sdcard to be his profile image so what is `path/to/file.png` ?

Comment: [See This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)

Comment: Please let us know which one is more efficient :)

Comment: @yahya ok when it works i will

Comment: +1 for you ..... and `decodeFile` is better for me

Comment: Glad to be of some assistance.

Comment: i did actually ask it to @MattClark because he said he's gonna make some tests :) Anyway glad that you got your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try out the below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView iv_image,img1;
int column_index;
  Intent intent=null;
// Declare our Views, so we can access them later
String logo,imagePath,Logo;
Cursor cursor;
//YOU CAN EDIT THIS TO WHATEVER YOU WANT
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

 String selectedImagePath;
//ADDED
 String filemanagerstring;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    img1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    iv_image= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_signup_image);

    img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
            // select a file
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
       }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            //OI FILE Manager
            filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

            //MEDIA GALLERY
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);


            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

           imagePath.getBytes();
           TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
           txt.setText(imagePath.toString());

           Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
           iv_image.setImageBitmap(bm);



        }

    }

}

//UPDATED!
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
 imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

}
```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: don't i have to use on activity returns listener? or somethign ?

Comment: Note that method onActivityResult gets called once an Image is selected. In this method, we check if the activity that was triggered was indeed Image Gallery (It is common to trigger different intents from the same activity and expects result from each). For this we used SELECT_PICTURE integer that we passed previously to startActivityForResult() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
private final int GET_USER_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 10;

ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
        "Select Picture"),
GET_USER_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
});


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == GET_USER_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY) {

        if (data != null) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            try {
                File imageFile = new File(selectedImagePath);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile
                        .getAbsolutePath());

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
}

private String getPath(Uri selectedImageUri) {

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri,
            projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: what is `getPaht`, eclipse doesn't recoginze it