# Menu button to open the phone gallery and load any text file to app

Tags: android

iam developing an application.i have created a menu with a button.i want to open the gallery with that button and select any text file and load it.how would i do that.help me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You should implement file browser concept in your app which should browse the gallery and pick the android file and return file path to your app. i have done similar kind of project which can useful to you. i have made file browser library which browse the sd card and return the file path you pick. code can be found at  [github](https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Android-FileBrowser)