# Pick image from gallery without losing Extra

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)  to start an intent to throw the gallery. Everything is ok except that before calling `startActivityForResult` I put some extras to intent and when I manage the selected image, the Extras are always null. How can I solve? Is there a better way to save my Extras?