# How to select video images from gallery in android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have a problem that i want to select images and video from gallery in aNDROID
i have used following codes but unsuccessful.

1. `setType("*/*);`
2. `setType("video/*");`
3. `setType("image/*");`
4. `setType("image/* , video/*");`
5. `setType("image/* video/*");`
6. `Intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`
7. `Intent i=  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   i.setType("*/*");
   startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);`

Answer (score 9):

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*,video/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

you'll find more details at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: Hi Alaa,  Its code is working in Activity only.. not for Fragment Class.. can u tell the way this code working in fragment class.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is working for me to load video in a fragment:

```
private void loadVideo(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), LOAD_TESTING_VIDEO);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == LOAD_TESTING_VIDEO) {
           // Get the Video from data
           Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
           String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
           Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedVideo, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
           if (cursor != null) {
               cursor.moveToFirst();
               int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
               mediaPath1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
               //uptestVideoName is a EditText
               upTestVideoName.setText(mediaPath1);
               cursor.close();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    case SELECT_IMAGE:
            intent = createGetFileIntent(SELECT_IMAGE, "image/*");
            startForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
        case SELECT_VIDEO:
            intent = createGetFileIntent(SELECT_VIDEO, "video/*");
            startForResult(intent, 1);
            break;



    private Intent createGetFileIntent(int fileType,
                                   String mimeType) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    }

    intent.setType(mimeType);

    switch (fileType) {
        case SELECT_IMAGE:
            intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.title_select_image));
            break;
        case SELECT_VIDEO:
            intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.title_select_video));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return intent;
}
```

Comment: Please, add comments to your answer.