# Get image content failing to open Gallery folders

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-gallery

Im creating an image converter app and need the user to select the image file from the device, im using an emulator and when i start the intent to pick a file from the gallery it displays the images in their folders but on clicking a folder, it just reopens the gallery and not the folder here's my code

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.selectf)),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            //Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
            // Get the path
            try {
                Path = getPath(this, uri);
                if(   Path.endsWith("png")  ||  Path.endsWith("gif")   ||    Path.endsWith("jpg")    ||    Path.endsWith("bmp")){
                    startprogress2();
                    progressDialog.onStart();
                    asyncTask = new loadAction();
                    asyncTask.execute();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.selecti,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                failtoloadtoast();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                failtoloadtoast();
            }
        }else{
            failtoloadtoast();
        }


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

keep in mind i have to enable the user to be able to select image files also from a file manager not only gallery as some formats aren't read by gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like this:

**Intent:**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
             startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

**To fetch that result:**

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

       switch(requestCode) {
       case 0:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
               Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
               String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
               Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
               cursor.moveToFirst();
               int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
              //file path of selected image
               filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
               File f = new File(filePath);
               filename= f.getName();

               Toast.makeText(SiteViewFieldCreate.this, "Your Path:"+filePath, 2000).show();
               Toast.makeText(SiteViewFieldCreate.this, "Your Filename:"+filename, 2000).show();
               cursor.close();

           }
           break;
     }
     }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android).
Hope this will give you some solution.

Comment: nope.. no difference, i have a feeling this is just on the emulator