# how to use photo taken by the application?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I have an Android application, which takes a photo if you hit a button:

```
@Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
      }
```

How can I use the picture and load it into an existing ImageView? (It should overwrite the default picture)

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android intent - pick image from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298629/android-intent-pick-image-from-gallery)