# Pick the photo from gallery

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImage.toString());
    ImageView image1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    image1.setImageBitmap(image);
    String ABC ="ABC";
}
```

I get null value for the Bitmap image. How should I change the code so that I can get the value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app

Comment: Ssorry, i still cannot solve the problem

Comment: i had that problem when i tried to take a photo that not actually  on the device from google photos.
please check if it happen with phone galary .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView image1;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (data.getData() != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                image1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }

        } else
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private String getPath(Uri selectedImageUri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert the Uri to bitmap. Directly call the below method to set the image to image view.

```
image1.setImageURI(selectedImage);
```

**EDIT**

You can get the bitmap from uri like this.

```
Bitmap image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
```

Comment: i still have to figure out why it can null values, because i need to convert it to base64 to store it in the database later on.

Comment: I think you missed read external storage permission. Just add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> and check once.

Comment: 01-05 22:31:31.456  16473-16473/com.example.lean.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lean.myapplication, PID: 16473
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/242424 }} to activity {com.example.lean.myapplication/com.example.lean.myapplication.MyActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri

Comment: Add  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in manifest file...it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for getting image from gallery.

```
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
 String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath,
                    null, null, null);
 c.moveToFirst();
 int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
 picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
 c.close();
 setPic(picturePath);


private void setPic(final String path) {
    int targetW = imageview.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageview.getHeight();

    final BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
  if (requestCode == 2) {
        Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
        String fileUriString = selectedImage .toString().replaceFirst("file:///", "/").trim();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImage.toString());
        ImageView image1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image1.setImageBitmap(image);
        String ABC ="ABC";
}
    }
```

Comment: what are you getting ? print fileUriString value whether it contains value or not.

Comment: I just edit my code.. try that if it doesn't work refer this blog http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/20/select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-and-show-it-in-an-imageview/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code this wokrs well for me :

Open the gallery and select your image :

```
Intent g = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
g.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(g, FROM_GALLERY);
```

**FROM_GALLERY** is defined as int.

Get the image and set it to imageView :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == FROM_GALLERY resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
         Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
         String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
         Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

         cursor.moveToFirst();
         int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
         String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
         cursor.close();

         ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
         image1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you!!!

Comment: Have a look at this for some explication : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app?lq=1

Comment: 01-05 22:42:21.916  22150-22150/com.example.lean.myapplication E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException