# Android studio: Click picture or choose from gallery

Tags: android, camera

I am new to android studio, I want my app to have the ability to click picture along with the option to choose picture from the gallery. Is there a way use inbuilt camera app for this purpose? I am able to use inbuilt camera app but not able to add the option to choose image from gallery.
Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app