# UnsupportedOperationException while picking Image from Gallery

Tags: android, media, unsupportedoperation

In some cases, when I try to pick Image from gallery I get this error

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException,Unknown URI:
>   content://media/external/images/

My Code to pick image is as below :

```
 try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No Application Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: either it doesn't like the `content://` schema or the file type of the image

Comment: selecting gif image with intent?

Comment: I am also using the same code,it's not showing any error for me.

Comment: @yazhini in some case intent will throw this error

Comment: @Yazhini for me also it is not showing any error in testing but as the app is live there is the error stated in crash report

Comment: @Ajay what can be the solution? Any idea ?

Comment: have you try this ?intent.setType("image/*"); as well neha please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2508138/3514144

Comment: @Ajay I thought it may not be required as `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media` is for Images type only though will try adding.

Comment: ya atlist try because there is no issue in code so we hope this work