# cannot access gallery android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I am using this code to pick image from gallery it was working but now it has stopped working

```
(items[item].equals("Change from Library")) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_FILE);
```

onActivity Result

```
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String url = "";
                String pictureDirectoryPath= Functions.getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(),selectedImage());
```

Here is my Android monitor log when the button to pick image gallery is clicked

```
58.819 8995-8995/com.example.sharique.loginapp W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-01 08:39:00.375 557-683/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService:     Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of:     com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@52921524 attribute=null,      token = android.os.BinderProxy@5296999c
```

Comment: Provide a better error log.

Comment: Also do you have all permissions for it?

Comment: Why you think that selectedImage uri point to some path?

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it has stopped working" means.

Comment: @Arslan.H yes i have permissions

Comment: @CommonsWare i mean it doesnt respond when i click 'change from library' it doesn't do anything except for closing the dialog box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 500);
```

onActivity Result

```
Uri selectedImageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
String mPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
```

getPath() method

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

if your target and compile sdk higher than lollipop then you have to add request permission code refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) link

Comment: Note that your `getPath()` method will return useless values, such as paths to files on removable storage that you do not have rights to access.

Comment: havent found any help :(