# How can I access to gallery and pick image without startActivityForResult/onActivityResultin?

Tags: android

I have a CardView (player's CardView ) with overflow menu. The menu has a edit and delete, when you click on edit, launch a dialog and  there are a lot of attributes for this player in this dialog. One of this, is a ImageView (player's photo) and when you click launch an Intent and you can pick a photo in the gallery. 
My question is how can I get that image and set my ImageView?

In a different thread I saw they are used `startActivity` and `onActivityResult`, but in my CardView I can't use this methods.

**I cant use onActivityResult and startActivity for manage a picture that i pick from gallery**

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app)

Comment: no, because i cant use **onActivityResult** and **startActivity** for manage a picture that i pick from gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use onActivityResult then there's a solution that may work for you.

Create a second Activity aka (PickImageActivity)

Store a ResultReceiver as argument in the Intent

Start the startActivityForResult from that Activity onCreate

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

In the onActivityResult you have something like this:

```
 Bitmap received = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()));
 Bundle result = new Bundle();
 result.putParcelable(RESULT_KEY, received);
 ((ResultReceiver) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER_KEY)).send(RESULT_OK, result);
 finish();
```

So you may start it like:

```
Intent pickImage = new Intent(this, PickImageActivity.class);
pickImage.putExtra(RECEIVER_KEY, new ResultReceiver() {
       public void onReceive(int resultCode, Bundle data) {
               //Work with the data received here trough RESULT_KEY
       }
});
```

If Bitmaps dont fit your memory do send the content file path.

This solution does work and I had implemented it in a project but refactored for activityResult cause if the previous Activity is destroyed you will not receive the Data

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marcos! i dont understand this: **Bitmap received = //get from the data** received is the image that i pick in my gallery? or wath? thanks!

Comment: thanks, but i dont understand how i get the image after picked

Comment: Check answer, theres topics on that on stackoverflow, but i added